# показывает ошибку 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

есть два файла: основной и config.py с настройкой.При попытке присвоить переменной значение из конфика 
выходит ошибка "'str' object is not callable".Как можно исправить?
ошибка на строке 12,
конфик:

```
code = '0000'
```

основной файл :

```
import config
from tkinter import *
import basic
#
window = Tk()
window.geometry('150x110+500+300')
window.title('ввод пороля')
#
data = IntVar()
data2 = StringVar()
code = '0000'
code = config.code()
#
def CodeProgramm():
    window.destroy()
    win = basic.Basic()
    win.start()
def open():
    if data.get() == code:   
        CodeProgramm()
    else:
        data2.set('пороль не верный')
#
button = Button(window, text = 'ввести пороль', command = open)
entry = Entry(window, textvariable = data)
label = Label(window, textvariable = data2)
#
button.pack()
entry.pack()
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: 12я стока на 1 ниже... лучше скопируйте текст ошибки целиком сюда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`code` в файле `config` это не функция, а тут попытка использовать ее как функцию:

```
code = config.code()
```

Это неправильно, делайте просто присваивание:

```
code = config.code
```